# Need sample program to throw InterruptedException

Tags: java, multithreading

I am going through the **kathy sierra SCJP 1.5 Chapter 9(threads)** and there it is mentioned as:

> Notice that the sleep() method can throw a checked InterruptedException
>   (you'll usually know if that is a possibility, since another thread has to explicitly do
>   the interrupting), so you must acknowledge the exception with a handle or declare

I just need a sample program to know when it happens (which i can run on my machine)?

I googled but could not find any sample code to test this functionality..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();

        Thread interruptingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                // Let the main thread start to sleep
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                mainThread.interrupt();
            }
        });

        interruptingThread.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("I was interrupted!");
        }
    }
}
```

To walk through it:

- Set up a new thread which will sleep for a short time, then interrupt the main thread
- Start that new thread
- Sleep for a long-ish time (in the main thread)
- Print out a diagnostic method when we're interrupted (again, in the main thread)

The sleep in the main thread isn't *strictly* necessary, but it means that the main thread does get to really start sleeping before it's interrupted.

Comment: Thanks jon for your prompt answer..
Just curious to know is there any way, through which we can cause interruptedexception,other than interrupt method??

Comment: @javanoob: Not that I'm aware of... some other method can call `interrupt()` of course, so it may not be apparent to your code that `interrupt()` has been called, but that's basically how you interrupt the thread.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SleepTest1 extends Thread {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SleepTest1 st1 = new SleepTest1();
    st1.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon in Stack Overflow. Could you expand on this answer?

Comment: This code doesn't interrupt the sleep, it interrupts after the sleep. It's not quite what the OP is asking.